# Redraw Fragment in View after initialising Google Map - Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to display a Google Map on half screen of my profile view. In my `onCreate` method I created a new instance of an `AsyncTask` to retrieve latitude and longitude from Google servers via JSON. After receiving the result, I call:

```
GoogMapHandler gmh = new GoogMapHandler(fragmentManager, applicationContext);
gmh.initilizeMap(coord, "Username", "addressInfo");
```

Here is my `GoogMapHandler` class:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.internal.fm;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class GoogMapHandler {
    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private Context applicationContext;

    public GoogMapHandler(FragmentManager fmanager, Context applicationContext) {
        this.fragmentManager = fmanager;
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public void initilizeMap(LatLng coord, String username, String addrInfo) {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Fragment fragment = this.fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = this.fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            fragTransaction.detach(fragment);
            SupportMapFragment supportmapfragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragment;
            googleMap = supportmapfragment.getMap();

            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                        "Sorry! Unable to create map.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                Marker loc = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(coord).title("User: " + username)
                        .snippet(addrInfo));
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coord,
                        15));
                fragTransaction.attach(fragment);
                fragTransaction.commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, that I can't see the map, although I get no errors. As the View is already created, I tried to to "redraw" the fragment to display the map, but it's not working.

How can I achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Here is my `ProfileActivity`. As suggested, I used `onResume` to create the `AsyncTask`.

```
public class ProfileActivity extends BaseActivity {
    private String username, address, postalCode, country;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        Log.i("URL",
                "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                        + address.replaceAll("\\s+", "+") + ",+" + postalCode
                        + ",+" + country + "&sensor=false");

        new LocationTask(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                getApplicationContext())
                .execute("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                        + address.replaceAll("\\s+", "+")
                        + ",+"
                        + postalCode
                        + ",+" + country + "&sensor=false");
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        username = intent.getStringExtra(SearchResultsActivity.USERNAME);
        if (username != null) {
            setTitle("User: " + username);
        }


        address = intent.getStringExtra(SearchResultsActivity.ADDRESS);
        postalCode = intent
                .getStringExtra(SearchResultsActivity.POSTALCODE);
        country = intent.getStringExtra(SearchResultsActivity.COUNTRY);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(username);

        setContentView(textView);

    }
}
```

Profile Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_frame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.2" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Location Task:

```
public class LocationTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, String, StringBuilder> {

    private EditText address = null;
    private EditText postalCode = null;
    private EditText country = null;

    private Context applicationContext;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private LatLng coord;

    public LocationTask(FragmentManager fmanager,
            Context applicationContext) {
        this.fragmentManager = fmanager;
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }



    @Override
    protected StringBuilder doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(params[0]);
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                int b;
                while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stringBuilder;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(StringBuilder result) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String postal_code = null;
        String street_address = null;
        String country = null;
        try {
            String status = jsonObject.getString("status").toString();
            if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) {
                JSONArray results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");                 
                    JSONObject r = results.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONArray addressComponentsArray = r
                            .getJSONArray("address_components");
                    JSONObject geometry = r.getJSONObject("geometry");
                    JSONObject locationObj = geometry.getJSONObject("location");

                    coord = new LatLng(locationObj.getDouble("lat"), locationObj.getDouble("lng"));

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            GoogMapHandler gmh = new GoogMapHandler(fragmentManager, applicationContext);
            gmh.initilizeMap(coord, "Username", "addressInfo");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to remove this in my `ProfileActivity`:

```
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(username);

        setContentView(textView);
```

Removing it, solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

*I cannot comment*

Are you sure your code is going inside the IF block:

```
 public void initilizeMap(LatLng coord, String username, String addrInfo) {
    if (googleMap == null) {
       //are you getting upto here?
    ....
    }
 }
```

If SupportMapFragment is declared in your layout, I don't think detach will do anything meaningful here. The following should work:

```
public void initilizeMap(LatLng coord, String username, String addrInfo) {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        Fragment fragment = this.fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);            
        SupportMapFragment supportmapfragment = (SupportMapFragment) fragment;
        googleMap = supportmapfragment.getMap();

        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
                    "Sorry! Unable to create map.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Marker loc = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(coord).title("User: " + username)
                    .snippet(addrInfo));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coord, 15));
        }
    } else {
            Marker loc = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(coord).title("User: " + username)
                    .snippet(addrInfo));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coord, 15));
}
```

If the above is not working, the problem is unlikely to be in the block of code, rather, it's probably getting called before map is ready.
Please give us more info; tell us whether the AsyncTask may be returning the results before `onResume()` is being called.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am 100% sure that I am getting inside the IF block. I think the problem is that I can't call the AsyncTask in the `onCreate` method of the Activity. Because it won't wait until the `AsyncTask` is done (after I get the result from the `AsyncTask` I create an instance of `GoogMapHandler` and then initialise the map for the Activity. Is there something like an `onBeforeCreate` method?

Comment: Why don't you try calling the asynctask in `onResume()`?

Comment: I tried it, but I get the same result (no Google map displayed and no warning or error).

Comment: Is it possible for you to post more of your code? I'd like to see if I can run it

Comment: I don't really see any obvious red-flags here. I am assuming that you have ensured that the AsyncTask is producing the expected results and all the necessary IF blocks are being executed. Can you, just to make sure this is not some under-the-hood initialization issue, call `super.onResume()` before calling the Async, and finally, try using a `handler.postDelayed(<YOUR_ASYNC_IN_RUNNABLE>, 4000)` in `onResume()`

Comment: Thank you for your help! Which `handler` do you mean? Do I have to create one or do you mean the `LocationTask`?

Comment: Are you sure that I don't have to "redraw" the View or wait on the `AsyncTask`? The google map object is not null and should be fine.

Comment: Glad that you fixed it. We were busy looking for problems in the map :)

Comment: Haha yes, but it was a stupid mistake. Sorry for that.